# YouTube Video is not working in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, html, youtube

Here is iframe code. This is working properly in all browsers but not in iPhone 5. I am using custom play button on YouTube player screen.
I have already tried class="youtube-player" type="text/html" tricks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>YouTube</title>
</head>
<body >
<iframe width="940" height="529" frameborder="0" id="player" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yS2PQwPqsCs?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;hd=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That link is working on iPhone safari browser.

Comment: I am using custom play button on YouTube player screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying in simulator, this wont work. You can play YouTube videos in device only.